# Ruby on rails background processing and temporary data storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm interested in creating a system that can queue user ids into categories and then poll values at regular intervals in order to run some code with them.

I'm unsure of how to do this in rails however, but my first thoughts would be to have some sort of temporary db table that stores the ids alongside categories, and resets if the server restarts. I have no idea how I would implement the background process to repeatedly process entries. Perhaps I can possibly achieve all of this with some sort of background worker?

Comment: For executing background jobs with Rails, read up on ActiveJob: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For executing background jobs in rails there are so many ways so try anyone

```
sidekiq
delayed_job
microservices
```